# How to remove pg_catalog constraint in a Postgresql query?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, knex.js

I'm quite new to Postgresql,  working with PG 9.6 and here is a sample query:

```
select * from (select "posts".* from "posts" inner join "feeds" on posts.destination_feed_ids # feeds.id > 0 and feeds.name='Posts' inner join "users" on feeds.user_id=users.uid and not users.is_private where to_tsvector('pg_catalog.russian', posts.body) @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.russian', 'xxx')   union select "posts".* from "posts" inner join "feeds" on posts.destination_feed_ids # feeds.id > 0 and feeds.name='Posts' inner join "users" on feeds.user_id=users.uid and not users.is_private where
          posts.uid in (
            select post_id from comments where to_tsvector('pg_catalog.russian', comments.body) @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.russian', 'xxx')  
          )  union select "posts".* from "posts" where "posts"."user_id" = '48d85d83-b562-439f-addf-d75cd75d092f' and to_tsvector('pg_catalog.russian', posts.body) @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.russian', 'xxx')  union select "posts".* from "posts" where "posts"."user_id" = '48d85d83-b562-439f-addf-d75cd75d092f' and
          posts.uid in (
            select post_id from comments where to_tsvector('pg_catalog.russian', comments.body) @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.russian', 'xxx')  
          )  union select "posts".* from "posts" inner join "feeds" on posts.destination_feed_ids # feeds.id > 0 and feeds.name='Posts' inner join "users" on feeds.user_id=users.uid and users.is_private=true where to_tsvector('pg_catalog.russian', posts.body) @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.russian', 'xxx')  and "feeds"."id" in (5,10,11,12,15,16,17)  union select "posts".* from "posts" inner join "feeds" on posts.destination_feed_ids # feeds.id > 0 and feeds.name='Posts' inner join "users" on feeds.user_id=users.uid and users.is_private=true where
          posts.uid in (
            select post_id from comments where to_tsvector('pg_catalog.russian', comments.body) @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.russian', 'xxx')  
          )
          and "feeds"."id" in (5,10,11,12,15,16,17) ) as found_posts order by found_posts.bumped_at desc offset 0 limit 31
```

As you can see there are a couple of `pg_catalog.russian` which I don't understand their role in the query. Currently the query returns no result for 'no-ascii' results.

The query is constracted using a knex config file which has:

`textSearchConfigName: 'pg_catalog.russian'` in it.

What I want is to change the query (or database?) so that it can query for all utf8 strings.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/textsearch-controls.html

> to_tsvector([ config regconfig, ] document text) returns tsvector
>   to_tsvector parses a textual document into tokens, reduces the tokens
>   to lexemes, and returns a tsvector which lists the lexemes together
>   with their positions in the document. The document is processed
>   according to the specified or default text search configuration.

and further:

> The choices of parser, dictionaries and which types of tokens to index
>   are determined by the selected text search configuration (Section
>   12.7). It is possible to have many different configurations in the same database, and predefined configurations are available for various
>   languages.

in other words, if you remove `'pg_catalog.russian'` the default config will be chosen. And its not goin to be "any language" one.

In order to use FTS you need to know the language before using it. Usually it means when saving text to use it with FTS you save language in next column, so you could do smth like `select to_tsvector(language_column, body)` instead of fixed `russian` value...

Also you might [want to check the](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html) `default_text_search_config` which

> Selects the text search configuration that is used by those variants
>   of the text search functions that do not have an explicit argument
>   specifying the configuration. See Chapter 12 for further information.
>   The built-in default is pg_catalog.simple, but initdb will initialize
>   the configuration file with a setting that corresponds to the chosen
>   lc_ctype locale, if a configuration matching that locale can be
>   identified.

Not sure if `textSearchConfigName` affects that in any way or not